# Postgres - remove element from jsonb array

Tags: arrays, postgresql, sql-update, jsonb

I have an array of `jsonb` elements (`jsonb[]`), with id and text. To remove an element I could use:

`UPDATE "Users" SET chats = array_remove(chats, '{"id": 2, "text": "my message"')`

But I want to delete the message just by the id, cause getting the message will cost me another query.

Comment: Please provide a table definition and example values. I can derive that you are using Postgres 9.4, but that should be in your question, too. Do you want to remove the element from all rows like your example suggests or from just *one* row? Can there be various combinations of `id` and `text`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming missing information:

- Your table has a PK called `user_id`.
- You want to remove all elements with `id = 2` across the whole table.
- You don't want to touch other rows.
- `id` is unique within each array of `chats`.

```
UPDATE "Users" u
SET    chats = array_remove(u.chats, d.chat)
FROM  (
   SELECT user_id, chat
   FROM   "Users", unnest(chats) chat
   WHERE  chat->>'id' = '2'
   ) d
WHERE  d.user_id = u.user_id;
```

The following explanation matches the extent of provided information in the question:

Comment: Thanks actually that's exactly what I wanted